# Android Dialog changes the Activity variables on it's own

Tags: android, dialog, state

I have an `Activity form` in `Android` which user can fill out, basically some basic `EditText` fields. And then there is an option to add a new `Device` to the form so the structure looks something like this:

```
FormData{
    String name;
    List<Device> devices;
}

Device{
    String id;
    List<Accessory> accessories;
}

Accessory{
    String id;
    boolean isChecked;
}
```

When user clicks on `addNewDevice` a `dialog` will be displayed where user can see a list of `devices`. When the user selects on device in that `Dialog` a new `Dialog` will be displayed, where user can fill the data of that `Device` and click `addDevice`.

Once the `Device` has been added, the user can see it in the `Activity` where he saw the initial form in a `recyclerView`. Then the user has an option to add more `Devices` (like decribed previously) or to click on the previously added `device` in the `recyclerView` and see its contents that were filled out before and edit them if the user wishes.

In the `Activity` there are 2 lists:

```
List<Device> devices;
List<Device> addedDevices;
```

`devices` list is filled by fetching data from the backend and they should remain untouched after the initial request. This list is then used to display in a `Dialog` where user can select between different `devices` that he/she wants to start filling and adding to the form.

Once the `Device` has been filled out (after selecting the `addDevice` button, selecting a `Device` he wants to fill out from the `devices` list`and filling the`Device`form ) the`Device`is then added to the list`addedDevices`and displayed in a`recyclerView`.

When one of the `addedDevices` is selected it is again displayed in a `Dialog` where the user can fill it out and edit it.

The question here is that once the user adds the first Dialog to the `addedDevices` list, it seems to save the `Dialog` state and for some reason change the `devices` list with the filled out data.

So when I click on the `addDevice` button again, it has saved the old data from the last form I had filled. And by checking the logs I found out that the `devices` list was being changed.

**MainActivity**

```
    private List<InstallationDocumentDevice> installationDocumentDevices;
    private List<InstallationDocumentDevice> devicesToAdd;     

    @OnClick(R.id.btnAddDevice)
    void onAddDevice() {
    Log.d(TAG, "size: " + installationDocumentDevices.size());

    InstallationDocumentDeviceSelectDialog dialog = new InstallationDocumentDeviceSelectDialog(context, installationDocumentDevices, new InstallationDocumentDeviceSelectDialog.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice) {
            Log.d(TAG, "devicey: " + installationDocumentDevice.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "installationdocdevices to add" + installationDocumentDevices.toString());
            onAddDeviceSelected(installationDocumentDevice);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
}

    private void onAddDeviceSelected(InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice) {
    InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog dialog = new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog(context, installationDocumentDevice, new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice) {
            devicesToAdd.add(installationDocumentDevice);
            addedDevicesListAdapter.setItems(devicesToAdd);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
}


private void initAddedDevicesList() {
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = clickedView -> {
        InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocument = (InstallationDocumentDevice) clickedView.getTag();
        Log.d(TAG, "dev to add" + devicesToAdd.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "installdoc" + installationDocument.toString());
        InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog dialog = new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog(context, installationDocument, new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
    };

    addedDevicesListAdapter = new AddedDevicesListAdapter(context, onClickListener);
    addedDevicesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    addedDevicesRecyclerView.setAdapter(addedDevicesListAdapter);
    addedDevicesRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(addedDevicesRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
}
```

Inside the `Dialog` fragments I do not access `MainActiviy` to change anything in there. Just passing on the variable into the `Dialog` and then `onclick` passing it back as it can be seen withing the `onClick` method.

And when opening the `Dialog` at any point.. either to add a new device or to change the device, the Dialog seems to only remember the last state of the `Dialog` and it does not load a new one.

Comment: Do you mean `InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog` dialog save the state (eg. name entered by the user)?

Comment: @Froyo yes it basically overrides the `devices` values once the `Dialog` is closed

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.Is it possible to add a screenshot?

Comment: @Froyo I do not think I can capture it with a screenshot. But lets say I pass the list of `Devices` into the `Dialog`. User selects a specific device and changes its `name` inside the Dialog. It should now return a new `Device` with a new name but instead it returns a new `Device` with a new name and changes the value in the `Devices` list.

Comment: Okay. You are passing `installationDocumentDevices` list to the dialog. It's a mutable list. It is possible that the code is changing it. Can you add code for `InstallationDocumentDeviceSelectDialog`?

Comment: @Froyo since the code is too long I will add all of the `Dialogs` into the pastebin. https://pastebin.com/sxr44m4Y . The issue here is not with the `name` but with the `isChecked`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203604/discussion-between-froyo-and-kataroty).